# Why is my Julia code is slow compare to C++?

Tags: performance, julia

I wrote the next code and measured its execution time.

```
function main()

    function Fib(n::Int)
        if (n == 0 || n == 1)
            return n
        end

        return(Fib(n - 2) + Fib(n - 1))
    end

    res = Fib(46)

    println(res)
end

@time main()
```

> > 1836311903
> > 123.625395 seconds (5.72 M allocations: 88.103 MiB, 0.02% gc time, 0.02% compilation time)2% compilation time)

I use VS Code and run the program with F1 -> Julia: Execute file in REPL. Isn't it slow for Julia compared to the same C++ code, which takes only about 16.5s? What am I doing wrong?

I heard that sometimes Julia could be slower than C++, but I hadn't expected such a big gap.

Comment: Are you comparing a REPL vs. an optimized C++ build?

Comment: I think the problem is that if  you evaluate Fib(n) you evaluate all function values from F(0) to(F(n - 1). So the function values for n < 1 are reevaluated many many times. Store the last evaluated value and use it when evaluating the next value.

Comment: The function as you wrote it uses tail recursion (i.e. recursion just at the `return` statement). C++ has specialized optimization for this case which Julia doesn't (it has this optimization as a macro call). If you want to compare apples to apples, write Fibonacci as a `for` or `while` loop.

Comment: `function fib(n)
  x,y = (0,1) ;
  for i = 1:n x,y = (y, x+y) ;  end ;
  x
end` for example (from Rosetta code website)

Comment: @DanGetz I though the same, but results using `perf` on Linux shown that this was not actually the bottleneck, so I got curious and found that this is because the function is included in another one (see my answer for more information).

Comment: @tadman The Julia interactive command-line REPL gives the same performance than executing a script on my machine so it is not the issue. The compilation time is also negligible (2% in the OP question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Julia is much slower in this benchmark because **`Fib` is not a top-level function**.

---

This benchmark overall measures the cost of function calls. Julia function calls tend to be more expensive than C++ one **by design**. Indeed, as stated in the [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/functions/):

> **Every function in Julia is a generic function**. A generic function is conceptually a single function, but consists of **many definitions**, or methods. The methods of a generic function are stored in a *method table*. 
> Given the call `f(x,y)`, the following steps are performed: first, the method table to use is accessed as `typeof(f).name.mt`. Second, an argument tuple type is formed, `Tuple{typeof(f), typeof(x), typeof(y)}`. [...]. This tuple type is looked up in the method table. 
> This dispatch process is performed by `jl_apply_generic`.

I tried to profile your code with a low-level profiler and I can confirm that **most of the time is spent in `ijl_apply_generic`** which is the generic dispatch mechanism. To be more precise, about 60% of the time is spent in that, 5% in integer boxing, and 5% in few other Julia internals like the stack management. Put it shortly, most of the time is simply pure overhead.

That being said, **Julia can apparently optimizes this dispatch mechanism if `Fib` is a top-level function**. I guess it consider `Fib` as a closure internally in your code and it is harder to optimize closure because of their fundamentally more dynamic behavior. What this means is that **you just need to move the `Fib` function outside the `main` function so to make the function much faster**.

Here is the corrected code:

```
function Fib(n::Int)
    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n
    end

    return(Fib(n - 2) + Fib(n - 1))
end

function main()
    res = Fib(46)
    println(res)
end

@time main()
```

Here are results on my machine for `Fib(42)`:

```
Initial Julia code:     12.859 seconds
Fixed Julia code:        1.100 seconds     <-----

Unoptimized C++ code:    1.265 seconds
Optimized C++ code:      0.593 seconds
```

Note that the Julia version is 1.9.4 and the C++ code has been compiled with Clang 16.0.6 (using the flags `-O3 -march=native` for the optimized version).

The Julia version is still not as fast as the C++ implementation, but "only" about twice slower. This is because **Julia does not implement the Tail Call Optimization** (TCO) while C++ compilers (like Clang) generally does. This is apparently because of the multiple dispatch mechanism discussed above (see [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/tail-call-recursion/87847/2) discussion).

In the specific case of Fibonacci, note that this implementation is fundamentally inefficient! Indeed, one can simply use an **iterative implementation** without recursive calls and get much better performance (even in C++). In general, (non-inlined) function calls are expensive whatever the target language so they should be avoided in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The excellent answer by @JérômeRichard clearly demonstrated the Tail Call Optimization (TCO) issue in Julia. However, by avoiding recursion one can write an optimized Julia version that's more than 3X faster than the equivalent C++. Here is an optimized Julia version without recursion:

```
function Fib(n::Int32, cache::Dict{Int32, Int32})
    haskey(cache, n) && return cache[n]
    (n == 0 || n == 1) && return n

    result = Fib(n - Int32(2), cache) + Fib(n - Int32(1), cache)
    cache[n] = result
    return result
end

function main()
    cache = Dict{Int32, Int32}()
    res = Fib(Int32(46), cache)
end
```

and C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int Fib(int n, std::unordered_map<int, int>& cache) {
    if (cache.find(n) != cache.end())
        return cache[n];

    if (n == 0 || n == 1)
        return n;

    int result = Fib(n - 2, cache) + Fib(n - 1, cache);
    cache[n] = result;
    return result;
}

int main() {    
    std::unordered_map<int, int> cache;
    int res = Fib(46, cache);
    std::cout << res << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Finally the respective timings:

```
Julia: 2.167 μs (10 allocations: 3.64 KiB)
C++:   7.2 μs (GCC 9.4.0)
```

**Edit:**

I compiled the C++ function with a newer compiler, GCC 12.1.0, and the timing now gets closer to Julia. In both cases I turned on the highest level of optimization, `g++ -Ofast -march=native`.

```
Julia: 2.14 μs (10 allocations: 3.64 KiB)
C++:   2.80 μs (GCC 12.1.0, still 30% slower than Julia)
```

Comment: I think you forgot about opimization flags during C++ compilation. Because on my computer with optimized exe, I am getting 3μs while Julia gives 9μs. Or perhaps I am just missing something with Julia(I fully copy-paste your code).

Comment: Yes, I turned on the highest level of optimization, `g++ -Ofast -march=native`, but the version of GCC compiler is a bit old 9.4.0, when I tried compiling with GCC 12.1.0 I got 2.8 μs at best, still 30% slower than Julia. In Julia, I just used `--optimize=3`.